# How to write and load GUI in linux?

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface

How to write and load GUI in linux  using qt or some other framework ?

any kernel api is available for that ?

Comment: Please use a search engine, there's tons of info out there. Stack Overflow is for _specific_ programming questions. (And Qt has excellent docs and tutorials.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no **kernel** api for qt or any other GUI toolkit on Linux. GUI toolkits are not a part of kernel.

For qt, please reference to http://qt-project.org/doc/